# Movie about killer army ants, involving a partially devoured cow in a barn and a scene with a man driving around dropping dynamite into ant hills

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, b-movies

In the 90's, I watched part of a color movie about a swarm of killer army ants.  These were normal sized ants, it's just there were so many and they were so voracious that they were dangerous.   I watched the movie on TV, I am unsure if it was a TV-edit of a theatrically released movie or if it was a straight-to-TV release.  I was a little kid at the time so I didn't have this terminology, but it may have been a B-movie.

I recall one scene in which the police investigate a barn, and upon opening the door, they discover the ants devouring a cow; it's partially eaten and covered in ants.  I believe the police are then attacked.  I recall another scene, that I suspect was the climax, in which a man drives around a field, dropping dynamite into the ant hills.  I think ants may have been climbing up his vehicle, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Shades of "[Leiningen Versus the Ants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leiningen_Versus_the_Ants)."

Comment: Phase IV,  probably - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Bcs3_b3VXSU

Comment: or maybe "Legion of Fire: Killer Ants! ", one of the best terrible films ever made

Comment: Was this a documentary? Sounds like any ordinary Texas fire ant.

Answer (score 15):

Is this ***[Legion of Fire: Killer Ants!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_of_Fire:_Killer_Ants!)*** AKA *Marabunta* (1998)...?

> *Legion of Fire: Killer Ants!* (alternatively titled *Marabunta*) is a 1998 made for TV horror movie, made for the Fox TV channel.

As indicated above, this is a '90s TV movie about killer ants. The ants in this movie eat people and animals alive and leave little more than bones behind when they're done with a meal. They're depicted with pretty poor CGI though, so they look very fake.

Regarding the two specific scenes you mentioned, there's a scene around the 55 minute mark where a farmer and a police officer enter a barn, and the ants are shown crawling all over the corpse of a cow. The ants then attack the farmer and the cop, so that's a perfect match for the first scene you described.

> [image: Image of soldier ants eating a cow, from "Legion of Fire: Killer Ants!" (1998).]
>
> <sub>*Legion of Fire: Killer Ants!* (1998)</sub>

There doesn't seem to be a perfect match for the second scene you described, with a man driving around a field dropping dynamite into ant hills (and ants possibly climbing up his vehicle), but those individual elements can be found in separate scenes.

For example, there's a scene around the 30 minute mark where two boys find an enormous ant hill in a field. There's a scene around the 1 hour and 5 minute mark where the ants are shown climbing up the side of a police officer's pick-up truck (shortly after that, he's shown driving it around with the ants crawling up his legs). And there's a scene around the 1 hour and 21 minute mark where the main characters drive up to a dam in a field and use bundles of dynamite to blow it up and flood a valley to wash the ants away.

I've added the trailer below, but you can watch the full movie on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ePpDemxKt8).

Answer (score 6):

It's possible this is [*Legion of Fire: Killer Ants!*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0122603/) (1998).  IMDb gives the following synopsis:

> A hive of South American, killer ants has been lying dormant in Alaska for ten years until seismic activity causes subterranean warming, awakening the ants. While many residents of Burley Pines, Alaska are being eaten alive, a small group races to survive and to find a way to stop the ruthless ants.

I haven't seen it, but there are [numerous reviews](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0122603/reviews) which contain details that make it sound like the movie you're looking for.

> One guy is in a truck driving in circles **while fire bombs go off on either side of the truck**, no matter where he is at any given moment.

> Have a father **driving another ute and getting ants crawling up his leg** resulting in him not getting out of the ute but driving around almost uncontrollably in a deadly manner to all bystanders,

> my favorite scene is when the two police officers are at the farm and the farmer who live there have dug holes in the ground and poured gasoline into them to kill the ants, **one of the cops fall into one of the pits** and the other one runs over there and shout: "Don't use your gun, the place will blow up!"